# Do not send gmail notification when user trying to change their email from the app firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have my change email page in my app. And when I changed it. Firebase always send me gmail notifications like this for ex.

Is there anyway to disable it?
[image]
code:

```
_resetEmail(
    String email,
    String userUid,
  ) async {
    try {
      UserCredential;
      await auth.currentUser!.updateEmail(email);
      await Database().email(email, FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);
    } on FirebaseAuthException {
      print('error');
    }
  }
```

Comment: While you are using admin SDK, update user email using [`updateUser()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user) rather than using change email method so you can avoid sending notification. If you are insisted on using the client SDK, opt to use [custom email handlers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler)

Comment: can you have a look at my comment?

Comment: Yeah I can see your comment but when I view your updateUser() link I can't fine the dart code

Comment: Have you checked this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#update_a_users_profile)?